# How to fix Android BLE SCAN_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED on Nexus 5?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having this `onScanFailed` error code on some devices (LG to be more detailed) when discovering BLE devices on android. The code works as expected on another devices.  How can i fix it?

I use BLE API 21+ and the following code to discover:

```
ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setReportDelay(discoveryDelay)
            .build();
```

Here are the full sources:
https://github.com/4ntoine/protobuf-ble-rpc/blob/hi-p/android/client/src/main/java/com/googlecode/protobuf/blerpc/BleRpcConnectionFactory.java#L362

Comment: is your LG is pre lolipop?

Comment: no, it's Marshmallow. But the app is targeted to pre-Marshmallow so it's not permissions issue

Comment: try like this way new ScanSettings.Builder().build() for scanSettings  not sure but having same issue in android M

Comment: getting the same error if commented `.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some devices do not support all of the features of the new LE API.  The features are hardware specific and up to the manufacturer to enable.  The best approach is to check for the supported feature before building the filter and settings.

```
bluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedFilteringSupported();

bluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported();
```

I haven't found any issues with issuing filters when `OffloadedFiltering` isn't supported.

If `OffloadedScanBatching` isn't supported, then you should not set a report delay.  Attempting to set a report delay of anything other than `0` will result in an error.

Comment: that information is very helpful, going to check it

Comment: does `http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanFilter.Builder.html#setServiceUuid(android.os.ParcelUuid)` work only if  `isOffloadedFilteringSupported ` returns `true` ? it's not described in docs

Comment: confirmed to be working now, thanks. Fixed by avoiding system filtering if not supported and added self-made filtering

Comment: I haven't dug deep enough into the source to figure out what changes with the `isOffloadedFilteringSupported`, but I would assume it had to do with whether the filtering gets handed to the HAL to be filtered by the hardware during a scan, or if it's done on the higher level after the scan is complete.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Alpha (SM-G850W Android 5.0.2) reports `isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported` as `true`, but does not work when `.setReportDelay(discoveryDelay)` is set.

Comment: This error also occurs for `SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER` if it is unsupported.